# R package "UsingR" in ubuntu

Tags: r, package

1.When I am trying to install UsingR package using it ends up showing few warnings:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpWornZQ/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘RColorBrewer’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘Formula’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘SparseM’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘HistData’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘aplpack’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘latticeExtra’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status
9: In install.packages("UsingR") :
  installation of package ‘UsingR’ had non-zero exit status
```

2.From the project website I could see the package for MACos or windows, but could not see it for ubuntu,

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UsingR/index.html

So is it possible to install on ubuntu R? or I need to tweak somewhere?

Comment: I could install it without any problems just a second ago (ubuntu 14.04, default repos + rstudio)

Comment: it looks like you are having problems with that package dependencies not the package itself, note that the package itself does not need compiling.

Comment: Then it can be a network problem, what do you think? :/

Answer (score 0):

Please try:
`sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

After that run this in your R environment:

```
install.packages("Hmisc")
install.packages("UsingR", dependencies=TRUE)
```